# ¿Cómo definir peticiones (las URLs) para realizar operaciones CRUD usando REST?

Tags: api, mongodb, rest

intentando cumplir las reglas de la arquitectura REST (especialmente las de documentos embebidos).
Tengo la siguiente colección:

**Conductores:**

```
[
    {
        _id:"5bec8251a91e0313c853041",
        nombre:"carlos",
        apellido:"Lopez",
        vehiculosAsignados:[
            {
                _id:"5be9221188c4d019a4647cdd",
                tipo:"camioneta",
                tareasRealizadas:[
                    {
                        _id:"5bef1f68e85f4711fc4476df",
                        descripcion:"Recoleccion de materias primas de la fabrica 1"
                    },
                    {
                        _id:"5bec8251a91e0313c853041d",
                        descripcion:"Recoleccion de papeleria y docuemntacion"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                _id:"5be9221188c4d019a4647cdd",
                tipo:"MicroBus",
                tareasRealizadas:[
                    {
                        _id:"5bef1f68e85f4711fc4476df",
                        descripcion:"transporte de empleados"
                    },
                    {
                        _id:"5bec8251a91e0313c853041d",
                        descripcion:"transporte al aeropuerto de ejcutivos"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

¿Cómo se deben definir las URLs para realizar operaciones CRUD sobre el documento embebido *tareasRealizadas*?.

y en el caso de lectura ¿como se define la url para aplicar filtros al documento embebido?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Como las tareas son entidades débiles podes hacer así**

Devolver todas las tareas de un vehículo

```
Get /vehículosAsignados/{idvehiculo}/tareasRealizadas
```

Si queres aplicar filtros se hace a través de queryStrings. Por ejemplo para devolver todas las tareas que contengan papelería en su descripción podes hacer

```
Get /vehículosAsignados/{idvehiculo}/tareasRealizadas?descripcion=papeleria
```

Para crear una tarea

```
Post /vehículosAsignados/{idvehiculo}/tareasRealizadas
```

Para obtener una tarea en particular

```
Get /vehículosAsignados/{idvehiculo}/tareasRealizadas/{idtarea}
```

Para eliminar una tarea

```
Delete /vehículosAsignados/{idvehiculo}/tareasRealizadas/{Idtarea}
```

**Como alternativa podes manejarte de la misma manera pero sin tener el vehículo en el path. En este caso tendrías que pasar el id de vehículo cuando creas una tarea y agregar un filtro por vehículo para listar las tareas. El delete y get no necesitan conocer el vehículo ya que solo necesitarías el id de la tarea**

Obtener una tarea

```
GET /tareasRealizadas/{idtarea}
```

Obtener lista de tareas de un vehículo

```
GET /tareasRealizadas?idvehiculo=23
```

Crear tarea

```
POST /tareasRealizadas pasando en el JSON { idvehiculo:23, descripcion: 'Llevar documentación'}
```

Eliminar tarea

```
DELETE tareasRealizadas/{idtarea}
```

Como notarás en este caso yo use plurales al definir los endpoints pero es perfectamente válido ponerlo en singular. Además se utiliza el método HTTP PUT para actualizar un elemento y PATCH para hacer actualizaciones parciales. Por supuesto que los endpoints pueden estar prefijados. Por ejemplo:

```
tudominio.com/apirest/v1/tareasRealizadas
```

Si querés algo mas avanzado podes leer sobre HATEOAS y Restful

Comment: Gracias amigo por la respuesta, pinta muy bien esta solución, pero sigo teniendo dudas con la manipulación de embebidos respetando REST, por ejemplo: que pasa si quisiera modificar  de la colección conductores el nombre del conductor & tambien eliminar la tareaRealizada con _id = “5bec8251a91e0313c853041d”; ¿en este caso como se haría? ¿Uso un PUT? (porque modifico) o ¿uso un PATCH? (porque modifico ciertas partes) y ¿cómo indico en la URI que la tarea la quiero eliminar y no editar? o ¿tengo que usar 2 peticiones para realizar los cambios?, gracias.

Comment: Para modificar el nombre de un conductor podes hacer un PATCH(porque es una modificación parcial) a /conductores/{idconductor}. Para eliminar una tarea usando la segunda forma que te mostré sería un DELETE /tareasRealizadas/5bec8251a91e0313c853041d. El método HTTP es el que define la operación a realizar. En efecto serían dos peticiones

Comment: si, pero en conjunto, ¿hacer la modificación del nombre Y borrar la tareaAsignada, debo tratarlas como peticiones diferentes siendo que son de la misma colección? asumiendo que esto implicaría llamar 2 veces a la BD

Comment: si en varios blogs hacen mencion de HATEOAS, me estudiar el concepto, gracias amigo

Comment: Si, tenes que hacer dos peticiones porque tenes que definir endpoints para cada tipo de objeto. El costo de hacer dos o N peticiones es mínimo comparado con la ventaja de tener una API sencilla. Fijate que siempre tenes los mismos métodos para cada tipo de objeto